# Singular matrix proof $A+a\cdot B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I find a problem which was closed due to not meet the guideline. I copy this problem here:

"$A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices. If $A+a\cdot B$ is singular for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then both $A$ and $B$ are singular."

This problem can be generalized to the following:

If $A+aB$ is singular for any $a$, where $x_1<a<x_2$, (it doesn't matter $0\in (x_1,x_2)$ or $0\notin (x_1,x_2)$), then both $A$ and $B$ are singular.

Comment: It's OK to ask and answer questions here, but you should be putting the question into the question, and writing your answer into an answer below.

Comment: Got it, I re-edit now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quicker proof. Note that $p(a) = \det(A + a\cdot B)$ is a polynomial. From the fact that $p(a) = 0$ for $a \in \Bbb R$, we know that $p$ is the zero polynomial. Clearly, $p(0) = 0 \implies \det(A) = 0$. To see that $\det(B) = 0$, note that
\begin{align}
\det(B) &= \lim_{x \to 0} \det(x \cdot A + B) = \lim_{a \to \infty} \det(a^{-1} \cdot A + B)
\\ & = \lim_{a \to \infty} a^{-n}\det(A + a \cdot B) = \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{p(a)}{a^n} = \lim_{a \to \infty}0 = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Great, this idea is to manipulate $a$ to make one matrix to be significantly dominated in "weight". But what about the generalized version? For example, if $a$ is bounded between some numbers $x_1<a<x_2$, can I use this method?

Comment: @MathFail $p(a)$ is a polynomial, so if $p$ is not the zero function, then it has only finitely many zeros. Thus, because $p(a) = 0$ for all (infinitely many) values of $a$ with $x_1<a<x_2$, it follows that $p(a) = 0$ for all $a \in \Bbb R$. From there, proceed in the same fashion.

Comment: If $a$ is bounded, for example, $1<a<2$, then how to use your previous trick to let $x\rightarrow 0$ or $x\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: As I said, the fact that $p(a)=0$ for all $a$ within the bounded interval is enough to deduce that $p(a)=0$ for all real numbers $a$. Now it is no longer the case that “$a$ is bounded”

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proof:

Since $M=A+aB$ is singular for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, Let $a=0$, so $A$ is singular. Next, we need to prove $B$ is also singular.

Assume $B$ is not singular, so $B^{-1}$ exists, $M=(AB^{-1}+aI)B=(AB^{-1}-(-a)I)B$.

Since $M$ is singular for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $\Rightarrow \det(M)=\det((AB^{-1}-(-a)I))\cdot \det(B)=0$.

By assumption, $\det(B)\neq 0\Rightarrow \det((AB^{-1}-(-a)I))=0$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$,

Note that $\det((AB^{-1}-(-a)I))=0$ means $-a$ is the eigenvalue of the matrix $AB^{-1}$, but we know the characteristic equation has at most $n$ distinct eigenvalues, so we can always choose $-a=\theta $ such that $\theta$ is not an eigenvalue of the characteristic equation. Namely, $\det((AB^{-1}-\theta I))\neq 0$. Therefore, we reach the contradiction, and the proof is completed.

---

Proof to the generalized version:

Above proof is to show $B$ is singular in general, and show $A$ is singular when $0\in (x_1,x_2)$

If $0\notin (x_1,x_2)$, then we assume $A$ is not singular, so $\det(A)\neq0$

$0=\det(A+aB)=\det\left(aA(\frac{1}{a}I+A^{-1}B)\right)=a^n\det(A)\det(\frac{1}{a}I+A^{-1}B)$

$\Rightarrow \det(\frac{1}{a}I+A^{-1}B)=0$ follow the similar argument as above, we can always find some $a=\theta , \theta\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $-\frac{1}{\theta}$ is not an eigenvalue of the characteristic equation. Namely, $\det(\frac{1}{\theta}I+A^{-1}B)\neq0$. Therefore, we reach the contradiction and the proof is completed.